# OpenGL shadow cube map - lookup problems

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, shadow

I am trying to use a cube map to create shadows for a point light.

I found various tutorial that helped me ([Pointers on modern OpenGL shadow cubemapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999830/pointers-on-modern-opengl-shadow-cubemapping), https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/169743-cubemap-shadows-for-pointlights, http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/courses/Realtime/repetitorium/2011/OmnidirShadows.pdf, ...) but I still have problems with the cube map lookup.

This shader creates the cube map (Format: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE):

```
//vertex shader
#version 330

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

in vec3 vertex;

out vec3 vertexModel;

void main()
{       
    gl_Position =  Projection * View * Model * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
    vertexModel = vec3(Model * vec4(vertex, 1.0));
}

//fragment shader
#version 330

uniform vec3 lightPosition;
uniform float lightRange;

out float fragDepth;
out vec4 fragColor;

in vec3 vertexModel;

void main()
{   
    gl_FragDepth = length(lightPosition - vertexModel) / lightRange;  
    fragColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

`lightPosition` is the position of the light in world space, `lightRange` is basically the zFar of the light's projection matrix.

The generated cube map looks good when debugging the application with gDEBugger.

Shadow lookup in the main shader:

```
float shadowValue(int i)
{
    vec3 lookup_vector = vertexModel - lightPosition;
    float dist = texture(shadowMap, lookup_vector).r; 

    float curr_fragment_dist_to_light = length(lookup_vector) / lightRange;

    float result = 1.0; 
    if (dist < curr_fragment_dist_to_light)
        result = 0.0;
    return result;

}
```

The result of this function is multiplied with the value frum the light calculation. The problem is that it returns always 1.0.

Has anyone an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to just return `dist` or `curr_fragment_dist_to_light` to see how that affects your scene?

Comment: yes. `curr_fragment_dist_to_light` is good - it gets greater farther away from the light. Thre problem is `dist` - the cube map lookup. It's always 1.0 (or at least a very high value) and is always constant.

This is the generated shadow map: [http://oi40.tinypic.com/6gcwte.jpg](http://oi40.tinypic.com/6gcwte.jpg) (I switched to back-face culling for the screenshot, normally I render the shadow map with front-face culling.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert the y-coordinate of the lookup_vector. While rendering (I presume) your y-coordinate points upwards but for OpenGL textures, y points downwards. Your scene is symmetrical, so your texture seems to be correct at first but it needs to be reflected - or just turn around your `lookup_vector`:

```
vec3 new_vec = vec3(lookup_vector .x, -lookup_vector .y, lookup_vector .z);
```

Then just look up the distance rendered to your shadow map as you already did:

```
float dist = texture(shadowMap, new_vec);
```

The depth to test against has to be computed like this:

```
vec3 abs_vec = abs(new_vec);
float local_z_comp = max(abs_vec .x, max(abs_vec .y, abs_vec .z));
float norm_z_comp = (z_far + z_near) /
    (z_far - z_near) - (2 * z_far * z_near) / (z_far - z_near) / local_z_comp;
float curr_fragment_dist_to_light = (norm_z_comp + 1.0) * 0.5;
```

`z_far`is your `lightRange`, `z_near` is the near plane equivalent. Last but not least, return your result:

```
float result = 1.0; 
if (dist < curr_fragment_dist_to_light)
    result = 0.0;
return result;
```

I based these computations on the answer to this question: [Cubemap shadow mapping not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176274/cubemap-shadow-mapping-not-working)

Comment: Because I can't answer on an edit suggestion: I use a samplerCube instead of samplerCubeShadow. SamplerCube lookups take a 3 component vector (float dist = texture(shadowMap, new_vec);).